# Yii disable access to a web page via url

Tags: php, yii

In my web application I want to disable access to pages via url even for authenticated users.How should I proceed? I googled it for tutorials but could not find one. How should I change my config/main.php file  .Any body kindly help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yii uses the `accessRules`, wich are located in the controller, to determine if someone can visit a page or not. When created with `Gii` there are default rules for this. On [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter) page you can find more information about this subject. Basicly make sure that your action with restriction is in a list that also have this line:

```
'users'=>array('admin'),
```

Or, if you use RBAC do it role base:

```
'roles'=>array('admin', 'editor', ...),
```

Comment: I know how to use  RBAC .but I want to disable access  via URL ... Ok i solved it  , it is automatically redirecting to login page...